# How to use an anchor date in SQL outside of the relevant table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to summarise some data I have by days that aren't included in the table.

I have a transaction table that includes a user_id, a transaction_id, created_at and completed_at.

Between the created_at and completed_at, a transaction is pending

I'd like to have the past 30 days and count of users that had pending transactions each day.

I've tried to 
A) generate a series of days then join my source table on. B) Select distinct created_at day then select from my source table
C) Export the full results to a googlesheet (too big)

```
WITH raw as (
  SELECT a.user_id, 
         t.id, 
         date_trunc('day',t.created_at) created_at,
        date_trunc('day',t.modified_at) modified_at
   FROM transaction t
 )
Select anchor_day,
        COUNT(distinct user_id) FILTER (where created_at <= anchor_day AND modified_at > anchor_day)
FROM raw;
```

Sample data

```
+---------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| user_id | transaction_id |        created_at         |       completed_at        |
+---------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| abcdefg |              1 | August 1, 2019, 12:00 AM  | August 7, 2019, 12:00 AM  |
| abcdefg |              2 | August 1, 2019, 12:00 AM  | August 9, 2019, 12:00 AM  |
| abcdefg |              3 | August 12, 2019, 12:00 AM | August 16, 2019, 12:00 AM |
| hijklmn |              4 | August 7, 2019, 12:00 AM  | August 11, 2019, 12:00 AM |
| opqrstu |              5 | August 8, 2019, 12:00 AM  | August 17, 2019, 12:00 AM |
| opqrstu |              6 | August 8, 2019, 12:00 AM  | August 16, 2019, 12:00 AM |
+---------+----------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|           Day            | Number of users with pending transactions |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| August 1, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 2, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 3, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 4, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 5, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 6, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         2 |
| August 7, 2019, 12:00 AM |                                         1 |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output for that (please not 100k records ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.dte,
       (select count(distinct r.user_id)
        from raw r
        where r.created_at <= gs.dte and r.modified_at > gs.dte
       ) as num_users
from generate_series(current_date - interval '1 month', current_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
order by gs.dte;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that looks like it worked but also made me realise, I think I asked the wrong question. How would I go about getting a table with user_ids and days when they didn't have pending transactions?

Comment: @user2741092 . . . This answers the question that you *did* ask.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.